# docker volume is removed but seems to be cached

Tags: mysql, sql, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have a `docker-compose.yml`:
```

```
version: '2'

volumes:
    db-data:
    vendor:
    var:

services:
    mysql:
        container_name: test-mysql-5.7
        image: mysql:5.7
        ports:
            - '3306:3306'
        volumes:
            - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
            - /home/ubuntu/www/prestashop-shops/test-ps/seeds:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test123
        restart: always
```

```

I run `docker-compose up -d` and it will bring up the container with the associated volumes. I have been playing with this and needed to tear it down to test the `docker-compose.yml` again.

I teardown by running `docker-compose rm -fsv` in the folder, which works in bringing down the container and some of the volumes.

I then run `docker volume ls | grep test- | awk '{print $2}' | xargs docker volume rm` the `test_db-data, test_var, test_vendor` volumes also created by the compose file.

I then run `docker-compose up -d` again, but when I go into the `mysql` instance and check the databases with a `SHOW DATABASES;` command. All the databases that were created before **are still there**.

I've checked the filesystem `/var/lib/docker/volumes/` to see if there are any physical files remaining for this and there are none.

I've tried renaming the `db-data` part of my compose file to something else, and it's still there.

I think this may be cached in the image but I don't remember building anything.

Wondering if volume data persists anywhere or is cached anywhere because I cannot get a clean instance of mysql deployed on my server now.

Comment: Is there any data in the databases, or just empty tables?  Do the files in your `seeds` directory have the corresponding `CREATE TABLE` statements?

Comment: Yes, the seed directory has a single script which creates two databases. For some reason these two databases already has tables created in them when there are no scripts to populate the newly created DBs with tables.